# Remove the duplicate values when the status is changing for same id

Tags: python, pandas, duplicates, conditional-statements

I want to remove rows where rule is showing NOT_OK when for one value it has already OK for the same id.

While for an id, if all values are NOT_OK, then keep all the values.

For example, for this dataset:

```
ID RULE
1   OK
1   NOT_OK
2   NOT_OK
2   NOT_OK
```

Desired output:

```
ID RULE
1    OK
2   NOT_OK
2   NOT_OK
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's say your dataset is a dataframe in variable 'df'. There is probably a more efficient way but this works:

```
ok_records = list(df['ID'][df['RULE'] == 'OK'])
df1 = df[(df['ID'].isin(ok_records)) & (df['RULE'] != 'NOT_OK')]
df2 = df[(df['RULE'] == 'NOT_OK') & (~df['ID'].isin(ok_records))]
final_df = pd.concat([df1, df2])
```

Comment: final_df should give you the desired output as stated in your question.

Answer (score 0):

The drop duplicates function should work: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html.

Just `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: No it is not working. As for id 1 there are OK and NOT OK. in that case i would like to keep only OK and in the id 2 there is no OK. I would like to keep both NOT OK. status